# Representing a ledger data-structure

Tags: purescript

Given that my Purescript program contains different types representing items that can be exchanged, for example `Vegetable`, `Milk`, `Meat` etc., what is the best way to represent a ledger data-structure that tracks the exchanges between participants? To simplify we can represent participants as `type Participant = Int`.

Comment: How would you represent the data in any other language?

Comment: How do you represent heterogeneous types in a common `Entry` structure?

Comment: Using a sum type perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`purescript-variant`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-variant/5.2.0) for open sums.

```
type Ledger products = Array (Entry products)

type Entry products =
  { date ∷ DateTime
  , product ∷ Variant products
  , unitPrice ∷ Int
  , quantity ∷ Int
  }
```

A Ledger type can then be instantiated for a particular set of products, such as `Ledger (milk ∷ Milk, vegetable ∷ Vegetable, meat ∷ Meat)`.